# How to set Python3 as default Python interpreter for VScode?

Tags: 16.04, python

I've successfully installed VSCode and extension for Python. Since Ubuntu comes with two Python2 version `2.7.12` and Python3 version `3.5.2`, VSCode uses Python2 as default interpreter. After opening VSCode I used command `Ctrl + Shift + P` to change preference and I typed Python Interpreter and selected Python3 from drop down, but I get the following error.

```
Failed to set 'pythonPath'. Error: Permission denied writing to file (file:///home/.vscode/settings.json)
Source:Python (Extension)
```

How can I access setting.json file and edit it to change interpreter to Python3?

Comment: Does that path exist?

Comment: This path exists `///home/.vscode` , I've used following command in terminal `cd ~/.vscode`

Comment: No, no. `~/.vscode` is not `/home/.vscode` rather it's `/home/$USER/.vscode`! Type `~/.vsocde` in terminal and press the return key and see the output!

Comment: After typing `~/.vsocde`  I get `/home/furqan/.vscode: Is a directory`

Comment: So make the changes if you entered `/home/.vscode` change that to `/home/furqan/.vscode`! to get vscode to write to that location!